# How to retrieve data from a specific cell, from a MySQL Database, in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a specific integer value from a column 'Balance' in my Database. However, i keep on catching an exception in my try-catch and this is the output;

Got an exception!
Before start of result set

Here is my code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 private void OKbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{         

    try{
        String password = PassJP.getText();
        int passint = Integer.parseInt(password);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banking application","root","");
              String query = "SELECT Balance FROM user WHERE Password =" +passint;

  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    int balance = rs.getInt("Balance");

     String WAmmount = WithAmmTF.getText();
    int WAmmountint = Integer.parseInt(WAmmount);

    int newbalance = balance - WAmmountint;
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `user`(Balance) VALUE ('"+newbalance+"') where Password="+ passint);

    conn.close();

    }
        catch (SQLException e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

EDIT:

i have also tried adding a while loop but that brought me another error like so:

Got an exception!
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Password=111' at line 1

Here is the code

```
 private void OKbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{         

    try{
        String password = PassJP.getText();
        int passint = Integer.parseInt(password);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banking application","root","");
              String query = "SELECT Balance FROM user WHERE Password = "+passint;

  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

  while(rs.next()) { 
      int balance = rs.getInt("Balance");
  String WAmmount = WithAmmTF.getText();
    int WAmmountint = Integer.parseInt(WAmmount);

    int newbalance = balance - WAmmountint;
        Statement s=conn.createStatement();

s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `user`(Balance) VALUE ('"+newbalance+"') where Password="+ passint);
  }

    conn.close();

    }
        catch (SQLException e) { 
        System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: After this line, `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);`, you have to do `while(rs.next()) {
    int balance = rs.getInt("Balance");
}`. If you only have one item, you still have to call the next(), but you can also keep the while loop and break after the first iteration.

Comment: @RyanD'souza i am now getting an error telling me there is a mistake in my SQL syntax yet i haven't touched my query.

Comment: A couple of things: have you printed out your constructed SQL statements just to make sure that the input variables are formatted correctly and the query is correct? You should also be using PreparedStatements as those will protect against vulnerabilities and correctly format input variables. What's the SQL error you're getting?